# Why does router disconnect from wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

Once in a while, all devices(connected to WiFi) get disconnected. They are not even visible in the networks list. However, all devices connected to a wired connection(only one device) are still connected to the internet? How do I solve this problem? If you unplug it and plug it back in, all goes fine. I use the DLINK DIR-655

Comment: Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Nothing, nothing?

Comment: What can I do??

Comment: This bug can be the result of many causes; in my occasion, totally different router, there was a cable improperly connected to one of our systems which caused an overload in the router's processor which affected only the wireless devices. Doesn't mean it will be the same for you, the problem might as just well be in your router. All you can really do is diagnose your entire network and see if there is something to be found; if not, start by replacing material...